# sudo: unable to resolve host ServerName (takes very long time to "sudo su" )

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, ubuntu-12.10

I use vmware and install ubuntu 12.10 as my guest OS.
and run my pc , my network interface is a wireless card
however everytime when i try to sudo , i should wait for a long time.
and echo

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ServerName pocUbuntu
[sudo] password for poc:
```

I search almost solutions by google , there is no solution can fix my problem.

when i type hostname

```
root@ServerName pocUbuntu:/home/poc# hostname
ServerName pocUbuntu
```

and there is my hosts file

```
 cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost pocUbuntu
127.0.0.1   pocUbuntu
127.0.1.1   pocUbuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and i can get the ack when ping the servername pocUbuntu

```
root@ServerName pocUbuntu:/home/poc# ping pocUbuntu
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
```

how should i do ? to fix the annoying problem.

Comment: Maybe a link where such questions have to be asked would be helpful

Comment: You computer name is ServerName, you've changed your computer'name. Here may be a bug, computer's name changed, while the hosts file not changed. You can just change you old computer'name to new one or just add a new item in the hosts file with `127.0.1.1  ServerName`

Answer (score 6):

try this: `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 hostname:localdomain hostname
```

or:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: did you reload your settings?

Comment: i reboot my pc..still has the problem